# ! Text line contains an invalid character

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr, invalid-characters

I'm trying to compile my R markdown file as PDF but i'm getting this error,

```
> ! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ## i Use the ^^[
                      ]8;;http://conflicted.r-lib.org/^^Gconflicted package^... 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Bellabeat.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Bellabeat.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

This is my YAML

```
title: "Bellabeat Project"
author: "Fatima"
date: "2023-12-14"
editor_options:
  markdown:
    wrap: 72
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
```

Surprisingly, the error only comes when I convert it into PDF. For HTML it runs pretty smooth.

Comment: These errors can be a pain to fix. Have you tried searching for the invalid character? Are you generating a `tex` document when you knit the pdf, this can be useful to hunt down the offending character.  Have you checked the tex. Have you followed through the guidance in the error message link:  https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/? One approach is to remove sections of the Rmd file until it knits successfully and then gradually add in the removed sections to identify the invalid character.

Comment: In addition to @Peter's comment, two suggestions: (1) If you have a percent sign `%` in any text/label, remove them and re-knit; if that works, add backslashes to them, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34580/82137. (2) I have occasionally needed to look at the intermediate `.tex` file(s) produced during knitting. While it is abysmally difficult (for non-TeX/LaTeX gurus) to parse out what you need, especially if you're never written in raw (La)TeX before, I suggest looking for stray backslashes (_very difficult!_) or embedded not-escaped percent signs. Good luck!